# Rook and ceph on kubernetes

Tags: linux, kubernetes, nfs, kubernetes-pod, ceph

I am new to Kubernetes. I am in need of integrating rook and ceph, adding NFS as block storage. Does anyone have any working examples? I followed **https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-ceph-cluster-within-kubernetes-using-rook** this document and I am getting errors(stuck at container creating, stuck at pod initializing) while creating ceph cluster in rook on Kubernetes. Any help would be appreciated.

```
kubectl get pod -n rook-ceph  

NAME                                            READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner-5bcd46f965-42f9r   0/5     ContainerCreating   0          12m
csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner-5bcd46f965-zszwz   5/5     Running             0          12m
csi-cephfsplugin-xcswb                          3/3     Running             0          12m
csi-cephfsplugin-zwl9x                          3/3     Running             0          12m
csi-rbdplugin-4mh9x                             3/3     Running             0          12m
csi-rbdplugin-nlcjr                             3/3     Running             0          12m
csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-6658cf554c-4xx9f      6/6     Running             0          12m
csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-6658cf554c-62xc2      0/6     ContainerCreating   0          12m
rook-ceph-detect-version-bwcmp                  0/1     Init:0/1            0          9m18s
rook-ceph-operator-5dc456cdb6-n4tgm             1/1     Running             0          13m
rook-discover-l2r27                             1/1     Running             0          13m
rook-discover-rxkv4                             0/1     ContainerCreating   0          13m
```

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you subscribe to the [ceph-users mailing list](https://lists.ceph.io/hyperkitty/list/ceph-users@ceph.io/). And noone is able to help without more details about the failing steps and the actual error messages.

Comment: Could you please provide logs from failing pods? Please use [`kubectl describe`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#describe) and add the output to your question, so we could see why the pods are in ContainerCreating status.

Answer (score 1):

Use `kubectl describe pod <name> -n rook-ceph` to see the list of events, it is on the bottom of the output. This will show where the pods get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It may be also the case that one of your nodes is in bad state, as it seems that some pod replicas are failing to start. You can confirm by running

```
kubectl get pod -o wide | grep -v Running
```

Possible all failing pods are running on the same node. If that is the case you can inspect the problematic node with

```
kubectl describe node [node]
```